# How to get LatLngBounds of visible region in titled map in andorid

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps-utils

I tried the following code.

```
    LatLngBounds b = googleMap.getProjection()
                              .getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    LatLng bNE = b.northeast;
    LatLng bSW = b.southwest;
```

It's not giving correct bounding coordinates if tilt is set to the map

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Google Maps API doc [VisibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion), the visible region for a map's camera can be in the form of a rectangle in case the camera is centered over the map region which will give you correct bounding coordinates. While it can also be in the form of a trapezoid, in case the camera has tilt, which is your case.

That's why you're getting wrong bounding coordinates!

Comment: Yes, you are right. In case of tilt, the visible region will appear to be a trapezoid but I have found that latLngBounds contain latlngs of the largest rectangle that can be created using all the latlng points (nearRight, nearLeft, farLeft, farRight). It means, latLngBounds must cover all the points of the visible region but it's not covering all. There is some part of the visible region which doesn't come under the latLngBounds.