# Get LatLngBounds of visible area with tilt = 65 degrees (google maps v2)

Tags: android, google-maps

This question [QUESTION LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268609/how-to-get-latlngbounds-of-visible-region-in-titled-map-in-andorid) have no answers.
I have this problem too.

At this [PICTURE](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/06/06/0019/0964/1262532/32/c1b714ec89.jpg) I getting bounds with padding.

When I set tilt to 65 degrees or other, I getting wrong bounds like this [EXAMPLE](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/06/06/0019/0964/1262532/32/4c30cb01aa.jpg).

So, how can I get true bounds with tilt?

Comment: You have to give a better format to your question, add the picture, the code that you've tried, and the result in the question itself not in a external links.

Comment: All information already in question.

Comment: With tilt I getting bounds of trapezoid and it not cover full visible area. I need get bounds of visible area from top to bottom with TILT.